# Undefined Behavior When Serializing filesystem::path Object

Tags: c++, serialization, path, c++17, undefined-behavior

I have the following code that works perfectly fine when testing the serializing and deserializing of the filesystem::path object:

```
#include <filesystem>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    namespace fs = std::filesystem;
    std::array<char, sizeof(fs::path)> arr;
    fs::path currentPath("./Icon");
    memcpy(&arr[0], &currentPath, sizeof(fs::path));
    currentPath = fs::path("./Characters");         //Change currentPath before performing memcpy deserializing for testing purposes
    memcpy(&currentPath, &arr[0], sizeof(fs::path));
    std::cout << currentPath.filename();
}
```

This works perfectly, serializing to the byte array and deserializing as expected. Until I use a different filepath such as swapping the initial path with the test path in the following:

```
#include <filesystem>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    namespace fs = std::filesystem;
    std::array<char, sizeof(fs::path)> arr;
    fs::path currentPath("./Characters");
    memcpy(&arr[0], &currentPath, sizeof(fs::path));
    currentPath = fs::path("./Icon");                   //Change currentPath before performing memcpy deserializing for testing purposes
    memcpy(&currentPath, &arr[0], sizeof(fs::path));
    std::cout << currentPath.filename();
}
```

When I run this version of the code the currentPath object ends up being corrupted.

Different behavior for two different but real directories leads me to believe that undefined behavior has slipped in somewhere but I am not certain exactly where. Again the directories used in the filepaths are real, but even if they weren't I couldn't see why it would effect the serializing and deserializing of the path object as the path object can be used to represent non existing filepaths.

Comment: *"This works perfectly"*. It might seem to works, but it is wrong too, `fs::path` is not trivially copiable.

Comment: Since a `fs::path` is a fixed size, ask yourself how it can support arbitrarily-sized paths. The only way this can work is to contain a dynamic container pointing to heap-allocated memory.  Therefore, you cannot copy the memory and consider it serialized. Use a proper serialization library/format instead.

Comment: As a close analogue, read this question: [How do I save and load a std::string with object serialization in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23176758/how-do-i-save-and-load-a-stdstring-with-object-serialization-in-c)

Comment: @Jarod42 Does the specification for objects contain information declaring the objects _not trivially copiable_? I usually look at the documentation provided by cppreference.com before I use anything but I did not see anything in the path class that stated it was not trivially copiable.

Comment: For your different behavior, maybe `path` uses small string optimization...

Comment: @Botje I assumed a dynamic container was involved and that the path object must have contained a pointer to heap-allocated memory, but I assumed that the pointer would have been serialized and deserialized and as such the new copy could continue operating using the originals heap allocation. The object must use a  pointer internally, is there a particular reason it is not copied with the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is for libcxx `std::filesystem` (Clang) but I assume other STL implementations have the same:

- a `fs::path` object [only has one field](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/libcxx/include/filesystem#L1507): `string_type __pn_;`
- the `operator=` simply [copies or moves the string](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/libcxx/include/filesystem#L971-L974): `__pn_ = __p.__pn_;`.

That means that when you do `currentPath = fs::path("./Icon");`, the existing string is freed by `std::string`'s `operator=` and the pointer you stashed becomes invalid. That it contains any recognizable value at all is up to many factors, including potentially the small string optimization, other threads' activity and dumb luck.

If you run this code under Clang's AddressSanitizer it will yell at you with roughly the same argumentation.